# Retrieving ContentDocument in Community Napili

Tags: lightning, community, napili, contentdocument

I have files attached as ContentDocument and I want to be able to retrieve it in a Community (Napili template) which has public access. My SOQL is not returning any row but a login user on Lightning experience is being able to get the Content Document.

Is there anything I can do to retrieve the Content Documen? Or any alternative solution?

Comment: does your content relate to an SObject and if so does the community user have access to that record?

Comment: Yes, it does relate to an SObject (Contact more precisely), I can view the contact detail under community, but it seems I can't retrieve ContentDocument but can do so with Attachment.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you have necessary permissions to access the ContentDocument. Use can find it with SOQL query, try the below query and see whether you have permissions

```
SELECT Id, Name, UserRecordAccess.HasReadAccess, UserRecordAccess.HasTransferAccess, UserRecordAccess.MaxAccessLevel FROM Object
```